# Deeplinks only work when using a slash in Jetpack Navigation

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-jetpack-navigation, android-deep-link

I'm trying to use [`<nav-graph>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#:%7E:text=When%20building%20your%20project%2C%20the%20Navigation%20component%20replaces%20the%20%3Cnav%2Dgraph%3E%20element%20with%20generated%20%3Cintent%2Dfilter%3E%20elements%20to%20match%20all%20of%20the%20deep%20links%20in%20the%20navigation%20graph.) generator to generate `<intent-filter>` elements in my `AndroidManifest.xml`

In one of the fragments in my `nav_graph.xml`, I added:

```
<deepLink app:uri="axzae://notifications" />
```

In the generated APK, the `AndroidManifest.xml` looks like below

```xml
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

  <data android:scheme="axzae" />
  <data android:host="notifications" />
  <data android:path="/" />
</intent-filter>
```

Now, the problem is with the additional `android:path="/"`. It made the app only respond to `axzae://notifications/` but not `axzae://notifications` (take note of the ending slash)

Is there anywhere I can make `<nav-graph>` to support `axzae://notifications` deeplink or without generating the `<data android:path="/" />` line?

Answer (score 1):

apparently, jetpack navigations can't resolve the generated `axzae://notifications/`. the app launched but it will always open up your `startDestination`. so it's actually broken.

another thing to note is it works fine for second-layer deep links. Example `axzae://notifications/settings` will work fine.

I will resort to a workaround for now by manually populating the TLD/host-only deep links in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<activity
  android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
  android:exported="true"
  android:theme="@style/Theme.App">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  
  <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/nav_graph" />

  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:scheme="axzae" />
    <data android:host="home" />
    <data android:host="notifications" />
    ...
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```